# Extjs - Panels with Re-sizing Browser

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, extjs4

Here is how I create the main app panel:

```
//for main panel scroll 
Ext.getBody().setStyle('overflow', 'auto');
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:  Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    id: 'Main',
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    initComponent: function () {
```

The current problem is that if I open the app in resized window (smaller), then enlargement it, the panel never takes the new browser size. how can i make it expand to fill the new size?

**UPDATE**

I've been trying to follow your instructions with no luck. my viewport was generated by sencha as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
   extend: 'MyApp.view.Main',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
       layout: 'fit',
});
```

Main.js view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel', 
    autoScroll: true, 
    title: 'Main',

        initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
            {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'center',
            split: true,
                    frame: false,
                    id: 'mapPanel',                             

                    }              
            ],          
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and part of app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    views: [
            'Main'
    ],
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.getCmp('mapPanel').add({
            requires: ['MyApp.Map'],
            items: [{
                  xtype: 'mymap',
              //      id: 'themap'
                }
            ]
        });
        Ext.getCmp('mapPanel').doLayout();

    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.Map', {
    extend: 'GeoExt.panel.Map',
    alias: 'widget.mymap',
    border: false,
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            map: map,
            height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are fixing panel dimentions when you configure it this way.
What you can do is use a Viewport component with Fit layout and your Panel as a child item of the viewport.

Viewport already reacts to the window size and Panel will 'fit' into the viewport through the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Ext.Viewport with layout: 'fit'.  For example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel', 
    autoScroll: true, 
    title: 'Main',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'fit',
        items: Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main')
    });
});
```